# How to replace undefined value with a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I tried to use this code:

```
if((data.memberData.workStreak || 0) >= 5){
            won+=400;
            embed.addField(message.language.get("WORK_CLAIMED_HEADINGS")[0], message.language.get("WORK_CLAIMED_SALARY", won))
            .addField(message.language.get("WORK_CLAIMED_HEADINGS")[1], message.language.get("WORK_AWARD"));
            data.memberData.workStreak = 0;
        } else {
            for(let i = 0; i < award.length; i++){
                if (typeof i === 'undefined') {
                   return '<:b_:682865394637078531>';
                }
                if(data.memberData.workStreak > i){
                    let letter = Discord.Util.parseEmoji(award[i]).name.split("_")[1];
                    award[i] = ":regional_indicator_"+letter+":";
                }
            }
```

But it did absolutely nothing.
[image]

Any help?

Comment: `+ (letter || 'string') +`

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use the `OR` operator and print string instead of undefined. In below statement if `a` is `undefined` then it will store empty string in `a` instead of `undefined`.

```
a = a || ''
```

Replace your line with below line:

```
let letter =Discord.Util.parseEmoji(award[i]).name;
OR
let letter =Discord.Util.parseEmoji(award[i]);
```

Please find working snippit below:

```js
const a = undefined;

console.log(a);
console.log(a || '');
```

Comment: It didn't work really much. It still saying undefined

Comment: I have updated the code for your scenario. Can you please check and if the problem still persist then Can you please create jsfiddle displaying your issue ?

Comment: Did you check the updated answer for your scenario ? Please check my answer again. Your jsfiddle is not working. We can also chat if issue is still there

Comment: I updated it but didn't really do much aswell. instead i got this: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/650265263006023680/685856942857388052/20200307_212942.png

Comment: on my config file. I put the `this.client.config.emojis.letters.s` to `<:grey:685784080637231208>`

Comment: can you please start a chat with me? It is difficult to solve before viewing running code. Use link to start a chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/10578638/prince

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow, so i don't really have that much rep to chat. Instead i have a glitch project that has that issue https://glitch.com/~aestetikxeno

Comment: Buddy, i need a way to talk to you. Will skype work for you ?? You are storing <:grey:685784080637231208> but when you are calculating the letter you are searching for underscore(_) which will not be there. So, i need to clarify what you need there ? Is it <:grey:685784080637231208> or something else ?

Comment: Use this room - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209209/undefined-error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209214/discussion-between-prince-and-veinify).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly, what this little code snippet is aimed to do.. But may this could help you?

```
let letter = Discord.Util.parseEmoji(award[i]).name.split("_")[1];
if (letter == undefined) {
   return '<:b_:682865394637078531>';
}
if(data.memberData.workStreak > i){
    award[i] = ":regional_indicator_"+letter+":";
}
```

Comment: Nope. Still saying :regional_indicator_undefined: